# Having python 3.4 find my custom package

Tags: python, import, module, package

I wrote a package in python and now I am trying to add it to my site-packages folder using a .pth file so that I can call it from anywhere using import statement, but it is not working.

`sste.pth` file in my site-packages folder

```
/scratch/automation/sste
```

sste folder structure

```
sste-\
     ---__init__.py
     ---module1.py
     ---module2.py
```

From what I understand when I launch python it should source the site_packages file, including my `sste.pth` file and add `/scratch/automation/sste` to the module list so I can import it by doing `import sste`, but I get an `import error`, and can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have directed Python to look for your module in `/scratch/automation/sste` when `sste` is itself a package. When Python looks in `/scratch/automation/sste` it is not going to find a package named `sste`, only `.py` files named `__init__.py`, `module1.py`, and `module2.py`.

In short, you should be telling Python to look in `/scratch/automation` for modules instead. Python's path is not a list of modules it can import, but rather a list of directories that may *contain* modules.

Also, check `sys.modules` to make sure the directories you expect to be in it are there.